# Unix Shell's '-x' Option in Perl

Tags: perl

When running a Unix shell script you can specify the `-x` option to have the shell print the actual command being executed, after all interpolation has been completed. For example, if we run this script (script.sh):

```
#!/usr/bin/sh

var='hello, world'
echo $var
```

with:

```
sh -x script.sh
```

we get

```
+ var='hello, world'
+ echo hello, world
hello, world
```

How can I get this same behavior for a perl script?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install my [`Devel::DumpTrace`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Devel%3a%3aDumpTrace) module and run

```
perl -d:DumpTrace my_script.pl
```