# How do I restrict Perl debugger output to lines in my own script?

Tags: perl

I'm running the debugger in noninteractive mode, with the output written to a file. I want to print out each line of my Perl script as it executes, but only lines in the script itself. I don't want to see the library code (File::Basename, Exporter::import, etc.) that the script calls. This seems like the sort of thing that should be easy to do, but the documentation for [perldebug](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug.html#Configurable-Options) only discusses limiting the depth for dumping structures. Is what I want possible, and if so, how?

Note that I'm executing my program as follows:

```
PERLDB_OPTS="LineInfo=temp.txt NonStop=1 AutoTrace=1 frame=2" perl -dS myprog.pl arg0 arg1
```

Answer (score 6):

By default, [`Devel::DumpTrace`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Devel::DumpTrace) doesn't step into system modules, and you can exercise fine control over what modules the debugger will step into (it's not easy, but it's possible). Something like

```
DUMPTRACE_FH=temp.txt perl -d:DumpTrace=quiet myprog.pl
```

would be similar to what you're apparently trying to do.

`Devel::DumpTrace` also does a lot more processing on each line -- figuring out variable values and including them in the output -- so it may be overkill and run a lot slower than `perl -dS ...`

(Crikey, that's now [two plugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13730315/unix-shells-x-option-in-perl/13730425#13730425) for `Devel::DumpTrace` this week!)

Comment: I have to look into installing this module on my system. It does look good.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about not wanting to step through functions outside of your own program?  For that, you want to use `n` instead of `s`.

From `perldebug`:

```
   s [expr]    Single step.  Executes until the beginning of another
               statement, descending into subroutine calls.  If an
               expression is supplied that includes function calls, it too
               will be single‐stepped.

   n [expr]    Next.  Executes over subroutine calls, until the beginning
               of the next statement.  If an expression is supplied that
               includes function calls, those functions will be executed
               with stops before each statement.
```

Comment: I'm running noninteractively, writing all of my output to a file. Hence, I'm not using either s or n. I edited my question to emphasize this.

Comment: Aha, sorry, I missed that.  I've never used that noninteractive mode.